# For which $x$ does the series $∑_{n=1}^∞(1+\frac{1}{2}+ \frac{1}{3}+⋯+\frac{1}{n})\, x^n$ converge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

Determine for what value of $x$ the series converges
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(1+\frac{1}{2}+ \frac{1}{3}+⋯+\frac{1}{n}\right) x^n $$

Observe that

$∑_{n=1}^∞(1+\frac{1}{2}+ \frac{1}{3}+⋯+\frac{1}{n}) x^n =∑_{n=1}^∞ (∑_{n=1}^∞\frac{1}{n}) x^n$

Can I consider $(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n})$ as $a_n$ and use the ratio test here or I must use the Hadamard?

Comment: $(1+\frac{1}{2}+ \frac{1}{3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n})\ne \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}$!!!!!!!!!!! Use that $(1+\frac{1}{2}+ \frac{1}{3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n})\approx \log n$.

Comment: Ratio Test is fine, so is the Root Test.  Then you need to deal with $x=\pm 1$, but the terms then don't go to $0$.

Comment: To nitpick more explicitly: you don't want to use $n$ as a bound variable within another expression where $n$ is the bound variable; your sum should be written as $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k\right)x^n$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that 
$$
1\le 1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}\le \log (n+1),
$$
and hence, using for example the comparison test, the radius of convergence of the series 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(1+\frac{1}{2}+ \frac{1}{3}+⋯+\frac{1}{n}\right) x^n $$
is $r=1$,  since the radius of convergence of both series
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n, \quad \sum_{n=0}^\infty \log n\, x^n
$$
is equal to $1$.

Comment: but the $n_0 =1$

Comment: @DianeVanderwaif changing, adding or deleting a finite number of terms doesn't change whether the series converges.

Comment: So, this lets you determine radius of convergence.  Now you need to investigate points on the circle $|x|=1$.

Comment: For the points on the circle $|x|=1$, we have $H_n x^n$ not converging to $0$. Thus, the series diverges for all $x$ on the unit circle.

Answer (score 4):

Let $H_n=1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}$,
Then $\frac{H_{n+1}}{H_n}=1+\frac{1}{(n+1)H_n}$ tends to 1, Thus the ratio of convergence is $R=1$ (D'Alembert criterion).

Now note that the Cauchy product of 
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n, \quad \sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac{x^n}{n}
$$
is exactly 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty H_n\, x^n
$$
Therefore,
$$
\forall x\in (-1,1), \sum_{n=0}^\infty H_n\, x^n=-\frac{ln(1-x)}{1-x}
$$